# How can I calculate the loss without the weight decay in Keras?

Tags: keras

I defined a convolutional layer and also use the L2 weight decay in Keras.

When I define the loss in the `model.fit()`, has all the weight decay loss been included in this loss? If the weight decay loss has been included in the total loss, how can I get the loss without this weight decay during the training?

I want to investigate the loss without the weight decay, while I want this weight decay to attend this training.

Comment: Can you share some code? specifically, how do you specify the "L2 weight decay", and what loss function is used when fitting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, weight decay losses are included in the loss value printed on the screen.

The value you want to monitor is the total loss minus the sum of regularization losses.

- The total loss is just `model.total_loss`
  .
- The regularization losses are collected in the list `model.losses`.

The following lines can be found in the source code of `model.compile()`:

```py
# Add regularization penalties
# and other layer-specific losses.
for loss_tensor in self.losses:
    total_loss += loss_tensor
```

To get the loss without weight decay, you can reverse the above operations. I.e., the value to be monitored is `model.total_loss - sum(model.losses)`.

Now, how to monitor this value is a bit tricky. Fortunately, the list of metrics used by a Keras model is not fixed until `model.fit()` is called. So you can append this value to the list, and it'll be printed on the screen during model fitting.

Here's a simple example:

```py
input_tensor = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
hidden = Conv2D(32, 1, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01))(input_tensor)
hidden = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(hidden)
out = Dense(1)(hidden)
model = Model(input_tensor, out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

loss_no_weight_decay = model.total_loss - sum(model.losses)
model.metrics_tensors.append(loss_no_weight_decay)
model.metrics_names.append('loss_no_weight_decay')
```

When you run `model.fit()`, something like this will be printed to the screen:

```
Epoch 1/1
100/100 [==================] - 0s - loss: 0.5764 - loss_no_weight_decay: 0.5178
```

You can also verify whether this value is correct by computing the L2 regularization manually:

```py
conv_kernel = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
print(np.sum(0.01 * np.square(conv_kernel)))
```

In my case, the printed value is 0.0585, which is indeed the difference between `loss` and `loss_no_weight_decay` (with some rounding error).